# jquery find image in array

Tags: jquery, arrays, indexing, find

hi I have an array of images

```
["img/wedgallery/1.jpg", "img/wedgallery/2.jpg", "img/wedgallery/3.jpg", "img/wedgallery/4.jpg", "img/wedgallery/5.jpg", "img/wedgallery/6.jpg"]
```

this is stored as a variable 'allpics' when an image is clicked I want to check for its index within this array.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery.inArray() http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/ ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need jQuery for that, but can do it with vanilla JavaScript. Use `indexOf()` ([MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)):

```
var index = allpics.indexOf( yourPic );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var allpics = ["img/wedgallery/1.jpg", "img/wedgallery/2.jpg", "img/wedgallery/3.jpg", "img/wedgallery/4.jpg", "img/wedgallery/5.jpg", "img/wedgallery/6.jpg"];

$('img').click(function(){
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    var index = $.inArray(src, allpics);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ekoceg/3/edit)*

You can use `jQuery.inArray()` <sup>[help](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)</sup>

```
var images = ["img/wedgallery/1.jpg", "img/wedgallery/2.jpg", "img/wedgallery/3.jpg", "img/wedgallery/4.jpg", "img/wedgallery/5.jpg", "img/wedgallery/6.jpg"];


$('img').click(function(){
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  var myArrIndexIs = $.inArray(src, images);
  alert(myArrIndexIs);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use jQuery, I'd imagine you would want to use `jQuery.inArray`. Alternately, you can use grep. It will find an element in array that satisfies a condition. the index is passed as a parameter in the callback.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

```
jQuery.grep( array, function(elementOfArray, indexInArray) [, invert] )
```

so

```
var img = //clicked elements src attrib

// s is the element selected from the array
var s = $.grep(allImages, function(elem, i) {
    if (img == elem.attr('src'))
    {
        //i is the index in allImages
    }
});
```